# What login name to use for Spring LDAP authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, ldap

I created a local LDAP server and added the user "djiao" with password "123456
[image]

Trying to implement authentication with Spring Security with Spring Boot. My webconfig class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("", "ldap://localhost:10389");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggerListener loggerListener() {
        return new LoggerListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

However I can't seem to login from the login page.

1. If I use djiao (cn) or djiao1 (uid), I will get 500.

   [LDAP: error code 34 - Incorrect DN given : djiao1 (0x64 0x6A 0x69 0x61 0x6F 0x31 ) is invalid]; nested exception is javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - Incorrect DN given : djiao1 (0x64 0x6A 0x69 0x61 0x6F 0x31 ) is invalid]
2. If I use dn "cn=djiao,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" as the username I will get "Bad credentials" error. And the password is simply 123456.

What should the username for login? Or am I missing something in websecurityconfig class?

Comment: As I can see you are using the AD connector which is looking for a property called SAMAccountName rather than uid. Pleas check with the "normal" Ldap Connector.

Comment: @daniel.eichten I am new to Spring Security. What changes do I need to use a normal ldap connector?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since from your code I could identify that you're using Spring-Boot.

This is what was working for us connecting to LDAP

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
        authBuilder
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
            .userSearchBase("dc=some,dc=domain,dc=com")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups,dc=some,dc=domain,dc=com")
            .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
            .contextSource()
                .url("ldaps://<ldap-server>")
                .port(639)
                .managerDn("cn=binduser,ou=users,dc=some,dc=domain,dc=com")
                .managerPassword("some pass")
        ;
    }
}
```

So in essence going for the `userSearchFilter` you'd have to define different values. If you use any LDAP besides AD your filter should by `"(uid={0})"` or if you wan't people to be able to use the email you could also go for `"(mail={0})"` or a combination like `"(|(uid={0})(mail={0}))"` which woul allow to use both.

If you go for ActiveDirectory – which I assume you do not based on what you have written above – it should be the `sAMAccountName` as stated above to allow people to just enter their ID in the domain like `MYDOMAIN\myusername` so the login would just be `myusername`.

If you need to connect to multiple LDAP-Server who share the same information for HA purposes you can do this through the `.contextSource().url()` call. If they carry different ones, e.g. 'EMEA', 'US', 'AP' you can combine these calls using:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
    authBuilder
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
        .userSearchBase("dc=emea,dc=domain,dc=com")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups,dc=emea,dc=domain,dc=com")
        .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
        .contextSource()
            .url("ldaps://<emea-ldap-server>")
            .port(639)
            .managerDn("cn=binduser,ou=users,dc=emea,dc=domain,dc=com")
            .managerPassword("some pass")
        .and()
        .and()
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
        .userSearchBase("dc=ap,dc=domain,dc=com")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups,dc=ap,dc=domain,dc=com")
        .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
        .contextSource()
            .url("ldaps://<ap-ldap-server>")
            .port(639)
            .managerDn("cn=binduser,ou=users,dc=ap,dc=domain,dc=com")
            .managerPassword("some pass")

    ;
}
```

BTW: this also allows you to combine different authentication mechanisms like InMemory (Default-Admin-Backdoor) with LDAP and/or JDBC.

Comment: It works now. Can you take a look at my other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748592/uncategorized-exception-for-using-correct-credentials-in-ldap-authentication) about authenticating against an institutional ldap server?